# How does sampling rate affect discrete filters?

Tags: discrete-signals, lowpass-filter

I am just starting to learn discrete filters and I could use some help. I understand continuous signals and filters.

I am trying to understand the math behind discrete filtering. For example in the s domain, a simple low pass filter can be recognized as $$\dfrac{1}{\tau s+1}$$
 How does sampling rate affect a discrete low pass filter?

Comment: The cut-off frequency of a discrete-time low pass filter is specified *relative* to the sampling frequency. So by changing the sampling frequency, you also change its cut-off frequency. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to understand where if the equation above was brought to the z-domain, where would the sampling time have a role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF we take the sampling period as T.First I will convert the filter to time domain impulse response as 
$$
h(s)=\frac{1}{\tau s+1}\\h(s)=\frac{1/\tau}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}
$$
this in time domain is
$$
h(t)=\frac{e^{-t/\tau}}{\tau}
$$
IF the above signal is sampled at time T the it can be written as
$$
h(Tn)=\frac{e^{\frac{-Tn}{\tau}}}{\tau}\\h(n)=\frac{e^{\frac{-Tn}{\tau}}}{\tau}
$$
if Z transform taken for the impulse response.Then the equation is
$$
H(z)=\frac{1/\tau}{1-e^{\frac{T}{\tau}}z^{-1}}
$$
Here we can see the sampling time coming in denominator which could put the pole inside or outside the unit circle

Comment: I understand the first part, up to h(n). Could you explain how you got H(z) from h(n)?

Comment: is T/\tau in H(z) supposed to be negative?

Comment: since h(n) is a geometric sequence we can find standard H(z) for h(n)   as     $$ \frac{1}{1-a^{-1}z^{-1}}$$  here a is $$ e^{T/\tau}$$ and T\/tau should be negative